# seprate values from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 string like this

```
var a= '12,13,14,15,16';
var b='p,q,q,p,q';
```

I just need like this 12,15 represents p
 and 13,14,16 represents q

How can I do this in Jquery/javascript.

Comment: what is the logic behind this. get the first 2 values, and the rest?

Comment: @lolka_bolka index in a = index in b

Comment: I just want to seprate both p's and q's.Their corresponding numbers also which is available in  var a= '12,13,14,15,16';

Comment: so you want the values for p and q to be set by the corresponding values in var a ?

Comment: You could use an associative array to create a kind of dictionary.

Comment: @Ankush Bhan you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
var a= '12,13,14,15,16';
var b='p,q,q,p,q';

var pValues=[], qValues=[]; //where to store the results

b.split(',').forEach(function(value, index){    //split the values from the b var
    var aa=a.split(',');                        //split the values from the a var
    if(value=='p') pValues.push(aa[index]);
    if(value=='q') qValues.push(aa[index]);
});
console.log("pValues: "+pValues);
console.log("qValues: "+qValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = '12,13,14,15,16';
var b = 'p,q,q,p,q';
var as = a.split(",");
var bs = b.split(",");

if(as.length == bs.length)
{
  var map = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < as.length; ++i)
  {
    var asv = as[i];
    var bsv = bs[i];
    map[asv] = bsv;
  }
  console.log(map['13']); //q
}
```

or:

```
var a = '12,13,14,15,16';
var b = 'p,q,q,p,q';
var as = a.split(",");
var bs = b.split(",");

if(as.length == bs.length)
{
  var map = {};
  as.map(function(asv,idx){
    return {asv:asv, bsv:bs[idx]};
  })
  .forEach(function(x){
    map[x.asv] = x.bsv;
  });
  console.log(map['13']); //q
}
```

In answer to your comment, perhaps something like this would be better:

```
var a = '12,13,14,15,16';
var b = 'p,q,q,p,q';
var as = a.split(",");
var bs = b.split(",");

if(as.length == bs.length)
{
  var map = {};
  as.map(function(asv,idx){
    return {asv:asv,bsv:bs[idx]};
  })
  .forEach(function(x){
    if(!map[x.bsv])
    {
      map[x.bsv]=[];
    }
    map[x.bsv].push(x.asv);
  });
  console.log(map['q']); //["13", "14", "16"]
  console.log(map['q'].join(",")); //"13,14,16"
}
```

Comment: I am not able to separate as 2 strings - 12,15 represents p and 13,14,16 represents q

Comment: @aniltc ..so effectively you're doing a "group by". See my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= '12,13,14,15,16';
var b='p,q,q,p,q';

function getRepresentative(srcA, srcB, valA)
{
  var mapIndexA = srcA && srcA.split(',').indexOf(valA);
  var mapB = srcB.split(',');


  return mapB && mapB[mapIndexA] || -1;
}

console.log(getRepresentative(a,b, '15'));
```

The function returns -1 if no corresponding map between A and B is found..

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes the two strings and splits them with the comma, then iterates over the symbol-token pairings one by one. Whenever a new symbol is discovered, it gets added to `symbols` and an empty array is added to `symbolToNumbers` so that numbers for this symbol can be pushed onto the array.

At the end, we can iterate over `symbols` to display the list of numbers for each symbol. This code will work for any variety of symbols, not just 'p' and 'q'.

```
function findElements(numbers, symbols) {
    var numberTokens = numbers.split(','),
        symbolTokens = symbols.split(','),
        symbolToNumbers = {},
        symbols = [],
        n = numberTokens.length;
    if (n != symbolTokens.length) {
        console.log('error: the lists must have the same length');
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        var number = numberTokens[i],
            symbol = symbolTokens[i];
        if (symbolToNumbers[symbol] === undefined) {
            symbols.push(symbol);
            symbolToNumbers[symbol] = [];
        }
        symbolToNumbers[symbol].push(number);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) {
        var symbol = symbols[i],
            numbers = symbolToNumbers[symbol];
        console.log(symbol+': '+numbers.join(', '));
    }
}

var a = '12,13,14,15,16';
var b = 'p,q,q,p,q';
findElements(a, b);
```

See this code running on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0e1g2ryf/1/